# AsStreams FireDAC got nil value from MemoryStream

Tags: arrays, delphi, insert, blob, memorystream

i was trying to insert a lot of info into my database `Access` and i am stuck on this exemple:

`(TableContact.FieldByName('foto') as TBlobField).SaveToStream(AQuery.Params.ParamByName('pFoto').AsStreams[I];`

Always my `AsStreams[I]` is nil

Trying to get it solved i tryed to do an loop adding my Streams into an Array and then insert them into my `AsStreams[I]`, but it was the same error (nil).

Exemple:

```
for I := 0 to Streams.Count - 1 do                                        
  (AQuery.Params.ParamByName('pFoto').AsStreams[I] as TBlobField).LoadFromStream(Streams[I]);
```

Anyone could help me?

`Full code downhere`

```
procedure TPrincipalController.SetDadosMemTableToBanco;
var
I: Integer;
AQuery: TFDQuery;

  function GetSQLMemTableToBanco: String;
  begin
    Result :=
      'INSERT INTO PESSOA (nome, telefone, email, foto, observacoes) ' + sLineBreak +
      '     VALUES (:pNome, :pTelefone, :pEmail, :pFoto, :pObservacoes); ';
  end;

  function GetSQLMemTableUpdateToBanco: String;
  begin
    Result :=
      'UPDATE PESSOA ' + sLineBreak +
      '   SET nome = :pNome, ' + sLineBreak +
      '       telefone = :pTelefone, ' + sLineBreak +
      '       email = :pEmail, ' + sLineBreak +
      '       foto = :pFoto, ' + sLineBreak +
      '       observacoes = :pObservacoes ' + sLineBreak +
      ' WHERE id = :pID; ';
  end;

  procedure SetArraySizeOnSQLChange;
  begin
    AQuery.Params.ArraySize := FTableContatos.RecordCount;
  end;

begin
  try
    AQuery := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
    try
      AQuery.Connection := TConexao.GetConexao;

      TableContatos.First;
      for I := 0 to TableContatos.RecordCount - 1 do
      begin
        AQuery.SQL.Text := GetSQLMemTableToBanco;
        SetArraySizeOnSQLChange;

        if ExisteRegistro(TableContatos.FieldByName('id').AsInteger) then
        begin
          AQuery.SQL.Text := GetSQLMemTableUpdateToBanco;
          SetArraySizeOnSQLChange;
          AQuery.ParamByName('pID').AsIntegers[I] := TableContatos.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
        end;

        AQuery.ParamByName('pNome').AsStrings[I] := TableContatos.FieldByName('nome').AsString;
        AQuery.ParamByName('pTelefone').AsStrings[I] := TableContatos.FieldByName('telefone').AsString;
        AQuery.ParamByName('pEmail').AsStrings[I] := TableContatos.FieldByName('email').AsString;
        AQuery.ParamByName('pObservacoes').AsStrings[I] := TableContatos.FieldByName('observacoes').AsString;

        (TableContatos.FieldByName('foto') as TBlobField).SaveToStream(AQuery.Params.ParamByName('pFoto').AsStreams[I]);

        TableContatos.Next;
      end;

      AQuery.Execute(TableContatos.RecordCount, 0);
    finally
     AQuery.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessageFmt('Erro ao incluir dados no banco. MSG -> %s', [E.Message]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What you name *full code* is not a [minimal, complete, verifiable and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please provide one that we can easily play with. And also provide somewhere for download a minimal actual Access database that your example will use to show the issue.

Comment: I got it.
1º Error: I could not use Update and Insert SQL on Execute;
2º Error: The attribution on AsStreams[I].
To solve it i must use a Stream object to save the image like this:
AStream := TableContatos.CreateBlobStream(TableContatos.FieldByName('foto'), TBlobStreamMode.bmRead);
        try
          AQuery.ParamByName('pFoto').LoadFromStream(AStream, ftBlob, I);
        finally
          AStream.Free;
        end;

Answer (score 1):

Solved using only Update on SQL and the attribution to the Field i needed to use like this:

```
AStream := TableContatos.CreateBlobStream(TableContatos.FieldByName('foto'), TBlobStreamMode.bmRead);
    try
      AQuery.ParamByName('pFoto').LoadFromStream(AStream, ftBlob, I);
    finally
      AStream.Free;
    end;
```